# Getting Horrible spots on textures

Tags: texturing

[image: why???]

I cant simply paint on certain surfaces and i am getting some weird spots on the surfaces that i can paint. Does anyone have a fix???

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time. You've already asked a question about not being able to paint on the whole model. I suggest using the [edit] link below your question to edit your question so that you are only asking about the spots.

Comment: Don't add any words indicating that the question is solved into the title; marking question as answered already did this

Comment: ok i will remove it. sorry for being such a headache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at zooming in closer to your paint surface, or maybe switch to the Fill tool since you are using Face Select Masking it might be easier to drop the color in that way.

The main reason is that 3d painting uses projection, and being far from the target can cause it miss. Smaller brush sometimes helps also.